# Spark creating huge amount of task when read from parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

Im having a very high tasks number on spark queries that read from small partitioned parquet data.

I'm trying to query a table that is stored in an S3 bucket in parquet snappy file format. The table is partitioned by date/hour (one partition example: '2021/01/01 10:00:00'). Each partition contains 15/18 files with a size between 30 and 70 kB.

A simple count by partition on 1 year of data is calculated using almost 20.000 tasks. My concern is why is spark creating so many tasks for reading so little amount of data. Is there any mechanism to make each single task read all the content from a single partition? I think it would be more efficient than 15 tasks reading 30kB of data each.

`spark.sql.("select count(1), date_hour from forecast.hourly_data where date_hour between '2021_01_01-00' and '2022_01_01-00' group by date_hour")`

`[Stage 0:>                                                      (214 + 20) / 19123]`

My spark version is 2.4.7 and configuration is in default mode.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of tasks are based on the amount of files that you are reading in. You can repartition after reading in the data.

Comment: The thing is, spark is creating more tasks than files. In the example I'm reading from 8760 files, but spark is creating 19000 tasks, and I cant figure out why, the files are small size..

Comment: So each partition only holds one file?

Comment: Each partition holds about 15 compressed files of 30kB aprox (Im editting the question... maybe I explained it wrong). I want each task to read all files from the same partition. Is that possible?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/animeshtrivedi/notes/wiki/Parquet-partition-calculation